# Bash Script to Python

Tags: python, bash

I want to convert a bash script to Python. I am having trouble in understanding some commands of bash. Here is the bash script -

```
L=`basename $PWD`
D=`dirname $PWD`
S=`basename $D`_$L

M=`ls -d /ccshare/linux/c_files/anand/*$S | head -n 1`

if [ -z $M ] ; then
    can not find module directory
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p modules && cp `find $M -type f` modules/ && chmod -R u+rw modules/
```

Comment: And your problems are what exactly? Have you taken a look at the documentation, e.g. http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

Comment: Yes i did take a look at that but still I cannot understand how to convert the M=`ls -d /ccshare/linux/c_files/anand/*$S | head -n 1` command into Python

Comment: On SO it is usually expected that you put some effort into problems before asking for help. You should be able to come up with some code you wrote, and have more specific problems than "I need help". I added a link to my earlier comment, which should help you research.

Comment: you mean you want someone else to convert this code into python for you?

Comment: I wanted to know what exactly is 'M' doing

Comment: the `glob` module is good for wildcard searches of the filesystem

Answer (score 3):

```
L=`basename $PWD`  # Get name of the current directory
D=`dirname $PWD`   # Get the path to the current directory, without its name.
S=`basename $D`_$L # Append the name of the current directory to the name of the directory below it.

M=`ls -d /ccshare/linux/c_files/anand/*$S | head -n 1` # A basically insane way to get the first file in that directory whose name ends with the $S name above.

if [ -z $M ] ; then
    can not find module directory # Broken; presumably meant to be printed to stderr.
    # (printf '%s\n' 'Cannot find module directory.' ?)
    exit 1 # Signal failure to any future commands.
fi

mkdir -p modules && # Make the modules directory.
cp `find $M -type f` modules/ && # A basically insane way to copy the files in "the module directory" to the directory named "modules"
chmod -R u+rw modules/ # Set permissions recursively, even though this directory will be flat.
```

It could be better written this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the name of the directory below this one.
dirBelow="${PWD%/*}"
dirBelow="${dirBelow##*/}"

# Make the modules directory.
mkdir -p modules
# Copy the files in the "module directory" into the directory named "modules".
find /ccshare/linux/c_files/anand/*"$dirBelow_${PWD##*/}" -type f -exec cp {} "$PWD/modules/" +
chmod u+rw modules/*
```

Comment: +1 for "basically insane way".